# JLabel not appearing until frame is moved out of the screen and back again

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I have the following fragment of code, where a JLabel is not displayed unless I move the JFrame out of the screen and back in again. I tried to change the layout from null to BorderLayout or FloatLayout without much luck so far. Any ideas?

```
public class StartPage extends Main{

// Global variables
private JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField();
private String infoLabel =  "<html>Bla, bla some text</html>";

// CONSTRUCTOR
public StartPage() {
    frame.setSize(1400, 1000);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    startPage.setBounds(0, 0, 1400, 1000);  
    startPage.setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().add(startPage);

    // TITLE LABEL
    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("My Title");
    lblTitle.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 30));
    lblTitle.setBounds(190, 150, 1000, 85);
    startPage.add(lblTitle);

    // TEXT LABEL       
    JLabel areaText = new JLabel(infoLabel, SwingConstants.CENTER); 
    areaText.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    areaText.setBounds(315, 220, 750, 300);
    areaText.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 15));  
    areaText.setVisible(true);
    startPage.add(areaText);
```

Comment: Don't call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame until after all components are added. Else they won't show up reliably. Also avoid absolute positioning unless you like difficult debugging sessions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it. You're a genius

Answer (score 2):

1. This line:

   ```
   frame.setVisible(true);
   ```

   Should be the last one in your program, it should be called after you've added all your components to it.
2. Another thing that is wrong with your code is this:

   ```
   startPage.setLayout(null);
   ```

   Calling `setLayout` null will break your GUI, it might seem easy for complex GUIs but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097)'s a good example of what happens when you run it in another machine with different resolution, OS, PLAF, etc. Use one or a combination of [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions, call frame.invalidate() after finishing layout or call setVisible(true) after finishing layout;

Comment: I am already calling `startPage.setVisible(true)` at the end, just forgot to add it to the piece of code above. Or are you referring to the whole frame, as startPage is just a panel?

Comment: You have to call frame.setVisible not the other fields. The JFrame is the window.

Comment: else you need to call frame.invalidate() in the end of the method

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that I validated the JFrame before adding all components. Right answer is a call to `frame.setVisible(true)` at the very end of my constructor

Comment: And that's EXACTLY what I meant to -.-