# BoxLayout using vertical and horizontal glue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Below is the code, which i got from [Creating two buttons at bottom left/right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690476/creating-two-buttons-at-bottom-left-right-corner/46691141#46691141) 
and i have included my attempt,(adding jpanel2)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonsLeftAndRight {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonsLeftAndRight()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button2");

        pane.add(button1);
        pane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        pane.add(button2);

        frame.add(pane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton b1 = new JButton ("A");
        JButton b2 = new JButton ("B");
        JButton b3 = new JButton ("C");
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel2.add(b1);
        panel2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panel2.add(b2);
        panel2.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        panel2.add(b3);
        frame.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

The problem is that BoxLayout can't be shared but i need to somehow do it so that i can get the vertical boxes

I'm trying to create `BoxLayout` GUI which involves using buttons and `JLabels`. In the below ASCII `B` represents buttons an `J` represents `JLabel`. Also im only keeping a bit space between buttons and `JLabels`

```
__________________________
|                        | 
|      B       J         |
|      B       J         |
|      B       J         |
|          J             |
|                        |
|Button1         Button2 |
|________________________|
```

Comment: What have you tried? You're throwing requirements to us, but have not shown effort into solving it yourself. Please [edit] your post with a [mcve] as I requested in the comments of my answer in your previous question

Comment: @Frakcool i updated it

Comment: I guess you haven't even read the links I posted... That isn't a MCVE... [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) while it is minimal, it is not complete, it lacks imports, a `main` method and variable declarations... If you want help from us, show some effort into doing it yourself first please, otherwise your question might get down voted and / or closed as it lacks the MCVE

Comment: @Frakcool i just updated it, does it follow MCVE now

Comment: A MCVE is similar to the code I posted in your previous question, you can actually copy-paste it and see the same output as me

Comment: can i copy paste ur code and add my attempt to it

Comment: Use nested panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout. For example  you create a panel with a horizontal BoxLayout for buttons 1 and 2. Then you can add to panel to another panel that uses a different layout manager.

Comment: *"can i copy paste ur code and add my attempt to it"* Of course you can, that's why I posted, but add your attempt to it. Also as already said by @camickr you can use other layout manager for another `JPanel` for the `JButtons` + `JLabel` and one for both buttons at the bottom...

Comment: @Frakcool im thinking of using gbc for the 3 labels and 3 buttons but the only problem is how do i create gridbaglayout using panel2.  
can i update the question with my attempt fro gridbaglayout and then u guys can tell me whats wrong

Comment: That's what you should be doing actually

Comment: got it thanks, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have many `JPanel`s, each with a different layout.

For this case I can imagine having `GridBagLayout` for the panel with buttons and labels which will be centered in the `JFrame`'s `BorderLayout.CENTER` alignment and having the buttons at the bottom with `BoxLayout` orientation

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ButtonsLeftAndRight {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel bottomPane;
    private JPanel centerPane;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ButtonsLeftAndRight()::createAndShowGui);
    }

    public void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());

        bottomPane = new JPanel();
        bottomPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        button1 = new JButton("Button1");
        button2 = new JButton("Button2");

        bottomPane.add(button1);
        bottomPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        bottomPane.add(button2);

        frame.add(bottomPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton b1 = new JButton("A");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("B");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("C");
        
        centerPane = new JPanel();
        centerPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        centerPane.add(b1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPane.add(new JLabel("Label 1"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        centerPane.add(b2, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPane.add(new JLabel("Label 2"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        centerPane.add(b3, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        centerPane.add(new JLabel("Label 3"), gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        centerPane.add(new JLabel("Centered Label"), gbc);
        
        frame.add(centerPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bottomPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

We have the labels positioned in the `gridx = 2` so we can have the bottom label in the `gridx = 1` position and this provides the extra space between the `JLabel`s and the `JButton`s with the space equals to the length of the bottom label.

This gives us the following GUI before and after resizing:

[image]

[image]

Of course there might be some other ways of doing it, however this is the first one I thought

---

### Note

- You added `setVisible(true)` twice, once is enough
- `frame.setSize(500, 500);` vs `frame.pack();` use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make this between adding jbutton and jlabel.

```
container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
```