# 2 Items in one BoxLayout-Row: one in the left, one in the right

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

My container JPanel has a boxlayout.
In the first row, another JPanel, two elements should be placed: a JLabel in the left and a JButton in the right.

How to place them there?

I can't use BorderLayout (so west and east) for the inner JPanel, because it would make the first row blow up taking the whole height which is really ugly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating two buttons at bottom left/right corner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690476/creating-two-buttons-at-bottom-left-right-corner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the first row, another JPanel, two elements should be placed: a JLabel in the left and a JButton in the right.

You can use a horizontal `BoxLayout` for that and add `"glue"` between the two components.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Invisible Components as Filler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) for more information.