# Can't draw line(method: paintComponent) - Java

Tags: java, swing, custom-painting

I'm trying to draw a line in a `JFrame`, but line isn't drawn.

I tried to use the method `setOpaque(true)` for `contentPane`, `lblNewLabel` and `l` but nothing changed. I also tried call `repaint();` outside this class but the situation is still the same. Here's the code:

```
public class DrawingClass extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public DrawingClass(int n, int s, int p) {
        Line l= new Line();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(700, 300, 480, 640);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image.png"));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 640);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        l.setBounds(0,0,480,640);
        contentPane.add(l);
        repaint();
    }

    class Line extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 12);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect a little line on the top left of the JFrame, above the background wallpaper, but nothing happen. It shows only the wallpaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. You're extending `JFrame` but you're not changing its behavior, so why are you doing that? `JFrame` is a rigid component, so it's never a good idea to extend from it, build your GUI based on `JPanel`s instead. See: [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)
2. Don't explicitly set the size of the `JFrame`, call `pack()` on it and instead override `getPreferredSize` from the `JPanel`, see: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)
3. You don't need to call `setOpaque(...)` in this case.
4. Don't use a `null-layout`, it might lead to [strange errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097), because [null Layout is Evil](https://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing)
5. We don't have access to your image so we cannot test the `ImageIcon` and it's also not related to your question. However you should [load your images as resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/loading-image-resource)
6. Don't explicitly set the bounds of each element, this is related to point **(4)** and you should use a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them to get your desired GUI.
7. Don't call `repaint()` that way, it has no effect, it is supposed to repaint your UI when there's a change in it. However there is no change at the start of your program.
8. You're breaking the paint-chain by not calling `super.paintComponent(...)` inside your `paintComponent(...)` method. Check the [Tutorial on Custom Painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) so that you learn how to do it properly
9. And be careful, as `paintComponents(...)` (With a trailing `s`) is different from `paintComponent(...)` (Look at your title)

So, after doing all of the above changes, we get to this simple program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DrawingClass {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new DrawingClass().createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        Line line = new Line();
        frame.add(line);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Line extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 15, 12);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(480, 640);
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]