# How to fix this AWT-EventQueue-0 exception

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, exception, awt-eventqueue

I write a Library login page with Java Swing and try to run it. The page can run properly but when I type in any username, choose a type and press login, it raises an `AWT-EventQueue-0: NullPointerException`.

The Library class deserializes two files containing the user and book info, and initialize them into objects.

User is the parent class of Member and Staff, Book class represents a book with its title, description, copy. The methods of these classes are all correct.

LoginWindow.java

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class LoginWindow {

    private JFrame frmLogIn;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    LoginWindow window = new LoginWindow();
                    window.frmLogIn.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public LoginWindow() {

        frmLogIn = new JFrame();

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblName.setBounds(23, 25, 46, 14);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().add(lblName);

        JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Type:");
        lblType.setBounds(23, 56, 46, 14);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().add(lblType);

        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(71, 22, 158, 20);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Staff", "Member"}));
        comboBox.setBounds(71, 53, 158, 20);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Login");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                if (!Library.users.containsKey(textField.getText())) {
                    new CreateUserWindow();
                    frmLogIn.dispose();
                }

                else if (!Library.users.get(textField.getText()).getUserType().equals(comboBox.getActionCommand())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "The user name and user type do not match, please try again.",
                            "User information mismatch", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }

                else {
                    String type = comboBox.getActionCommand();
                    if (type.equals("Staff")) new StaffWindow((Staff)Library.users.get(textField.getText()));
                    else new MemberWindow((Member)Library.users.get(textField.getText()));
                }
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(23, 88, 206, 23);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);


        frmLogIn.setTitle("Log in");
        frmLogIn.setBounds(100, 100, 268, 185);
        frmLogIn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmLogIn.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frmLogIn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Library.java

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.*;

public class Library implements Serializable{

    public static HashMap<String, User> users;
    public static HashMap<String, Book> books;

    public Library(boolean readFromSerialized) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        users = new HashMap<>();
        books = new HashMap<>();

        if (readFromSerialized) {
            ObjectInputStream u_in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./Assignment/data/Users.txt"));
            ObjectInputStream b_in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("./Assignment/data/Books.txt"));

            users = (HashMap<String, User>) u_in.readObject();
            books = (HashMap<String, Book>) b_in.readObject();

            u_in.close();
            b_in.close();
        }
    }

    public static void serializeToFile() {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream u_out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./Assignment/data/Users.txt"));
            ObjectOutputStream b_out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("./Assignment/data/Books.txt"));

            u_out.writeObject(Library.users);
            b_out.writeObject(Library.books);

            u_out.close();
            b_out.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
}
```

Error message shows that the following code snippet contains some error, the code is about user info validation:

```java
if (!Library.users.containsKey(textField.getText())) {
                    new CreateUserWindow();
                    frmLogIn.dispose();
                }
```

Comment: Please don't use the `back button` of your browser to edit your question. It breaks the changes made by others

Comment: And even if this wouldn't be the thousands repetition of the same question, your request is nowhere close to be a [mcve]. Please learn how and what to ask here before writing more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code:

1. Use of `setBounds` and use of `null-layout` (`setLayout(null)`), which is [evil](https://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing), as it might lead to annoying issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097), use proper [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) in order to make your application to render correctly in all OS and PLAFs.
2. Use of `public static` members, this might lead to inconsistencies in your application flow.
3. Now, your issue is that you create a **global** `textfield` variable but never initialize it (so it's `null`)

   ```
   private JTextField textField;
   ```

   But then, on your constructor you create another one with the same name, but it's a **local** variable:

   ```
   JTextField textField = new JTextField();
   ```

   And when you call this line:

   ```
   else if (!Library.users.get(textField.getText()).getUserType().equals(comboBox.getActionCommand())) {
   ```

   Java is using the **global** variable (which remember it's `null`), not the **local** one (which is initialized), in order to fix this, remove `JTextField` on the declaration of the **local** variable:

   ```
   JTextField textField = new JTextField();
   ```

   So, it becomes:

   ```
   textField = new JTextField();
   ```

   That's going to initialize the global variable and you will be able to use it in your `ActionListener`

Comment: I just fixed the scope issue but it still raises the same exception.

Comment: Well, unless you post the stack trace AND a [mcve] that addresses all the above recommendations made by me, I think I can't provide any more help. My guess is that it has something to do with your `static users` variable in the `Library` class