# JButton enabled when two textfields are equal

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm having trouble with making `JButton` enabled when two text fields in the same panel are equal. I tried adding an `ActionListener` but still nothing is happening and my `JButton` stays disabled. The same thing happened when I tried simply `str1.contentEquals(str2)`.

```
txtPassword = new JTextField();
txtPassword.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
txtPassword.setText("password");
txtPassword.setBounds(115, 49, 200, 20);
panel.add(txtPassword);
txtPassword.setColumns(10);
String str1 = txtPassword.getText();

txtRepeatPassword = new JTextField();
txtRepeatPassword.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
txtRepeatPassword.setText("repeat password");
txtRepeatPassword.setBounds(115, 124, 200, 20);
panel.add(txtRepeatPassword);
txtRepeatPassword.setColumns(10);
String str2 = txtRepeatPassword.getText();

JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Next >>>");
btnNewButton.setVisible(true);
btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        panelPYT.setVisible(true);
        panel.setVisible(false);

    }
});
btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
btnNewButton.setBounds(88, 182, 259, 50);
panel.add(btnNewButton);

txtPassword.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            same();
          }
          public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            same();
          }
          public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            same();
          }
          public void same() {
                 if (str1.equals(str2)){
                   btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);
                 }
                 else {
                   btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
          }
});

JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next >>>");
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        panelPYT.setVisible(false);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask], there you will find a link to how to create a [mre] which is a good starting point for us to help you. 2) Don't use `null-layout` and `setBounds` as [null layout is evil](https://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and causes a lot of problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785) when tested on other computers with different OS / screen sizes / resolutions / PLAFs / etc.

Comment: 3) You have a method `same()` inside your `DocumentListener` that doesn't seem right. 4) You only added your `DocumentListener` to the `txtPassword` field but not to `txtRepeatPassword`, probably you want to add it to it as well.

Comment: `if (str1.equals(str2))` will always evaluate to the same result, because you only assign str1 and str2 once.  The `=` statement is a *one time assignment.*  It does not create an eternal link between that variable and any future values that the getText() method might return.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding your listener to `txtPassword`, but I'm assuming that the user is entering their password into `txtPassword` first, and `txtRepeatPassword` second. Which means that when the user is done typing in the first field, the `DocumentListener` is done firing, and when they enter their password into the second one, the listener won't fire, because the typing is happening in `txtRepeatPassword`.

Long story short, just add the `DocumentListener` to both text fields.

```
DocumentListener dlist = new DocumentListener(){
    .... all your methods
};

txtPassword.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dlist);
txtRepeatPassword.getDocument().addDocumentListener(dlist);
```

Also you need to change

```
if (str1.equals(str2)){
    btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);
}else {
    btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

to

```
if (txtPassword.getText().equals(txtRepeatPassword.getText())){
    btnNewButton.setEnabled(true);
}else {
    btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

The way you had it, `str1` and `str2` were just holding the value of the their respective text boxes at the time of initialization. You want to compare the values they hold at the time of the listener firing, so you'll have to retrieve the value at that time.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't solve the problem, I have repeated the same method but for str2 and the result is still the same

Comment: I think that the problem has to be with the method, because when i change the if statement " (str1.equals(str2))" to " (str.equals("bruh")) and i insert bruh it still doesn't work

Comment: @AntoniSkup Oh I see what you did. I'll edit my answer in a minute here.

Comment: @AntoniSkup I've added to my answer. Let me know if that solves it for you.

Comment: Thanks man :D  I put the String str1 = textPassword.getText();
String str2 = textRepeatPassword.getText();

if (str1.equals(str2)){    in the button action performed section so each time i press it it checks if those two fields are equal

Answer (score 0):

> if (str1.equals(str2)){

The values of the strings don't change just because you type into a text field.

You need to get the text from the text field each time you do the check:

```
String str1 = textPassword.getText();
String str2 = textRepeatPassword.getText();

if (str1.equals(str2)){
```

Comment: Ahhh thanks man, this made me realise I need to put that in the button.actionPerformed  section

Comment: @AntoniSkup *I need to put that in the button.actionPerformed section* - no, that doesn't make sense. You need to invoke that logic from the DocumentListener code. The point of the code is to ENABLE the button only when the passwords match. So if the button is enabled you know the passwords match there is no need to do a check.