# How I can move up the line in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I create this class to draw the line and extend it as a component.

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent {

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawLine(30, 20, 80, 90);
    }
} 

...

frame.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
```

After drawing, when adding text fields to frame, it disappears.

```
frstVectorField = new JTextField("");
frstVectorField.setBounds(600, 50, 160, 30);

frame.add(frstVectorField);
frame.setLayout(null);.
```

Comment: Avoid the use of `null layout`, [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785). What do you mean by "move up the line"? For better help sooner post a proper [mre] that shows how your GUI look like and if / when resized how should the componenents behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default *content pane* is a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` layout manager. When you call method `add(Component)`, of class `JPanel`, the `Component` gets placed in the CENTER area of the `JPanel`. Hence a subsequent call to method `add(Component)` will replace the `Component` that was previously added, since the CENTER area can only hold one `Component`.

I recommend the tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)