# Swing Application not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hi im am working on my Java project which I have to create a login page for users to enter, and when login is successful, an alert is supposed to tell them that the login was ok. However, I am having some troubles as my application is not showing up at all, I think it is something to do with the code that I have written. Below is the code:

```
public class UserLoginPage implements ActionListener {
    //Put all JLabels,Frames and buttons here etc
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    JTextField userText = new JTextField();
    JTextField passwordText = new JTextField();
    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

    //Label for successful login
    JLabel success = new JLabel("Login Successful");

    //Default Constructor to add the frames and panels etc
    public UserLoginPage(){
        panel.setLayout(null);
        userLabel.setBounds(10,20,80,25);
        panel.add(userLabel);
        passwordLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);

        userText.setBounds(100,20,165,25);
        panel.add(userText);
        passwordText.setBounds(100,50,165,25);
        panel.add(passwordText);

        loginButton.setBounds(10,80,80,25);
        loginButton.addActionListener(new UserLoginPage());
        panel.add(loginButton);

        success.setBounds(10,110,300,25);
        panel.add(success);
        //success.setText();

        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new UserLoginPage();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button Clicked");
    }
```

I think the problem lies with `loginButton.addActionListener(new UserLoginPage());` But I might be wrong, do let me know of how to solve the problem, thank you.

Comment: This is Swing, not JavaFX.

Comment: `panel.setLayout(null);` and `.setBounds(...)` are the root of your problems. It may look good on your computer, but [maybe not good in someone else's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097). `frame.add(panel)` should be before `frame.setVisible(true)` as well.

Comment: The entirety of your main method can be replaced with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(UserLoginPage::new);`. No need for an inner class here.

Comment: Always use a LayoutManager. They make things much easier for the programmer and designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were correct. `loginButton.addActionListener(new UserLoginPage())` causes a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. The constructor is always calling itself without a base case to default to. You should be passing that very instance of the `UserLoginPage` as a parameter, not a new instance.

Use this code instead:

`loginButton.addActionListener(this);`

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues in your program:

1. `panel.setLayout(null);` and `.setBounds(...)`. You shouldn't be using `null-layouts`, as Swing has to deal with multiple PLAFs, OS, screen sizes and resolutions. You might end up with issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785). Pixel-perfect layouts might seem like the easiest way to create complex UIs but it's not, it'll just lead you to endless issues. Instead use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them.
2. `loginButton.addActionListener(new UserLoginPage());` You're creating a new instance of your program every time, and on every instance of it you're creating a new object because all your code is inside the constructor. Just, don't! It's a recursive call that finally creates a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, to solve this use `this` instead of `new UserLoginPage()`
3. `frame.setVisible(true);` this line should always be the last line in your program, after you've added everything to your `JFrame`, not before.

With the above recommendations, here's an updated version of your code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class UserLoginPage implements ActionListener {
    // Put all JLabels,Frames and buttons here etc
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel userLabel;
    private JLabel passwordLabel;
    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextField passwordText;
    private JButton loginButton;

    // Label for successful login
    private JLabel success;

    // Default Constructor to add the frames and panels etc
    public UserLoginPage() {
        
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        panel  = new JPanel();
        
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        
        userLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
        
        userText = new JTextField(10);
        passwordText = new JPasswordField(10);
        
        loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        success = new JLabel("Login Successful");
        
        loginButton.addActionListener(this);
        
        panel.add(userLabel);
        panel.add(userText);
        panel.add(passwordLabel);
        panel.add(passwordText);
        panel.add(loginButton);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(success, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new UserLoginPage().createAndShowGUI();;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Button Clicked");
    }
}
```

[image]