# Printing ArrayList to JLabel not printing on GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I am currently facing an issue where I have an `ArrayList` of answers to a question and I am trying to print out each answer to a JLabel as this will display the question being added to the question bank.

The problem is it will only print one answer and there could be 5 answers stored in the array.  It is printing it to the console I have tried putting `this.add(answerLabel);` inside the for loop and outside.

Am I approaching this the best way?

```
answerLabel = new JLabel();
answerLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);

for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
    answerLabel.setText("Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i));
    System.out.println("Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i));
    this.add(answerLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll need to consider is to create a new instance of `JLabel` once you've added the previous one

```
answerLabel = new JLabel();
answerLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);

for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
    answerLabel.setText("Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i));
    System.out.println("Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i));
    this.add(answerLabel);
    answerLabel = new JLabel();
    answerLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues with your code:

1. `setBounds` tells us that you're using `null-layout`, see: [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) and if that's still not enough to show what the problems with using it are, here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785) of those. Instead use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and let Swing do the calculations for you
2. You're calling `setText` on your `JLabel` everytime your `for` does an iteration, this is overriding what you had on the previous iteration, so you have 2 options:

- Create a new instance of a `JLabel` on every iteration

  ```
  JPanel pane = new JPanel();
  pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

  for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
      answerLabel = new JLabel();
      answerLabel.setText("Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i));
      pane.add(answerLabel);
  }
  this.add(pane);
  ```
- Create a single instance of `String` and append all your text to it, then call `setText` on your `JLabel` once with the value of that `String`

  ```
  String text = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++) {
      text += "Answer " + i + ": " + answers.get(i) + "\n"; //Replace this for a StringBuilder, just making this an example
  }
  answerLabel.setText(text);
  this.add(answerLabel);
  ```