# Overlaping when using .setText() for some reason

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a Jlabel called status that is empty. When I do `status.setText()` the first time it works normally but when I change it again it overlaps the first change instead of replacing it like it should. What is going on?

```
package panda.org;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class NumberGame implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel rules;
    JLabel rulesText;
    JLabel rulesText2;
    JLabel lets;
    JButton play;
    JButton exit;
    JPanel panel;

    Font myFont = new Font("Serif Plain", Font.BOLD, 15);

    NumberGame() {

        frame = new JFrame("NumberGame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Gaming MSI\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\download (1).png");
        frame.setIconImage(icon);

        rules = new JLabel("Rules: ");
        rules.setFont(myFont);
        rules.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 75);

        rulesText = new JLabel("We will pick a random number in the range of 1 -> 50.");
        rulesText.setBounds(100, 100, 315, 75);

        rulesText2 = new JLabel("Your job is to guess that number!");
        rulesText2.setBounds(100, 120, 315, 75);

        play = new JButton("Play");
        play.setBounds(150, 300, 100, 75);
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int failedAttempts = 0;

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Guess the number from 1 till 50");
                label.setFont(myFont);
                label.setBounds(150, 75, 315, 75);

                JLabel hints = new JLabel("");

                JTextField text = new JTextField();
                text.setBounds(250, 150, 100, 25);

                JButton check = new JButton("Check");
                check.setBounds(150, 150, 75, 25);

                double randomDouble = Math.random();
                randomDouble = randomDouble * 50 + 1;

                int randomInt = (int) randomDouble;

                double finalRandomDouble = randomDouble;
                check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        System.out.println(randomInt);
                        String nb = text.getText();

                        int change = Integer.parseInt(nb);

                        JLabel status = new JLabel("");
                        status.setBounds(150, 160, 1000, 100);

                        frame.add(status);

                        if(randomInt == change) {
                            status.setText("You chose the correct number!");
                            status.setForeground(Color.green);
                        }
                        if(randomInt != change) {
                            status.setText("Wrong choice! Try again.");
                            status.setForeground(Color.red);
                        }
                    }
                });

                rules.setText("");
                rulesText.setText("");
                rulesText2.setText("");

                frame.add(hints);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.add(check);
                frame.add(text);
            }
        });

        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.setBounds(350, 300, 100, 75);
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,"Are you sure want to exit?", "Exit",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    System.exit(0);
                }else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                }else {
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(play);
        frame.add(exit);
        frame.add(rules);
        frame.add(rulesText);
        frame.add(rulesText2);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NumberGame number = new NumberGame();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Someone asked for more code so this is all of my code! I hope this helps :D

The problem is in these lines

```
                        if(randomInt == change) {
                            status.setText("You chose the correct number!");
                            status.setForeground(Color.green);
                        }
                        if(randomInt != change) {
                            status.setText("Wrong choice! Try again.");
                            status.setForeground(Color.red);
                        }
                    }
```

This is how the result appears:
[image: this is a pic of whats happening]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some improvements to do in your code:

1. You're using `null-layout` and `setBounds(...)` which is [not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing) it will give you more headaches than solutions, it may seem like the best / easiest way to build complex GUIs but it's not, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785)'s an example of why. Swing has to deal with multiple OS, PLAFs, screen sizes and resolutions, let the [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) do that work for you, all you have to do is combine them.
2. Every time you call `check.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {`, you're creating a new instance of your `JLabel` named `status`, and because you're using `null-layout` and you're placing it in the same position, they're overlapping.

Follow the first advice given in this answer, rebuild the whole thing with layout managers, move the `status` label as a class member and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Thankyouu!! I didnt realize that every time I clicked the button it made a new status label, but now thinking about it, that makes perfect sense! thanks for the help!

Comment: I will also look into the layout managers

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
if(randomInt == change) {
    status.setText("You chose the correct number!");
    status.setForeground(Color.green);
}else{
    status.setText("Wrong choice! Try again.");
    status.setForeground(Color.red);
}
```

Comment: You also should post more of the code because you might be repeating the label creation in iterative code

Comment: It was originally an else but then it happened and changing it to two ifs didnt work so I came here