# Java Swing | The last JTextField doesn't sets to custom size

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm creating a Word Puzzle Solver. I created for loops to create a JTextField "grid".

[image]

When the last field in the lower right corner is created it does not resize to the size I entered. It is resizing to the size of frame.

My code:

```
public class SolverGUI {

    int sizeOfRect = 50;
    static int height = 5;
    static int width = 5;
    static JTextField[][] textFields = new JTextField[width][height];
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Word Puzzle Solver");

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        createWordPuzzleArea();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void createWordPuzzleArea() {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < width; i2++) {
                textFields[i2][i] = new JTextField();
                frame.add(textFields[i2][i]);
                textFields[i2][i].setBounds(10 + (i2 * sizeOfRect), 10 + (i * sizeOfRect), sizeOfRect, sizeOfRect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making the grid yourself, you could make use of [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid).

Making use of `setBounds` makes me think you're using `null-layout` which [is not right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing), it might seem like the best and easiest way to make a complex UI, but it isn't, if you don't believe me [check this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520492/jtable-not-showing-up-on-jframe-java/42521097#42521097). Swing has to deal with multiple PLAFs, OS, screen sizes and resolutions and thus pixel-perfect UIs aren't good, as you can see in the example everything breaks, and thus using layout managers like `GridLayout` solve these issues.

You can instead make it like this, and you're avoiding making the calculation of each cell yourself, and let the layout manager do that for you :)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridOfTextFields {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel pane;
    private JTextField[][] fields;
    
    private static final int ROWS = 5;
    private static final int COLS = 5;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridOfTextFields()::createAndShowGUI);
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };
        
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(ROWS, COLS, 1, 1));
        
        fields = new JTextField[ROWS][COLS];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                fields[i][j] = new JTextField();
                pane.add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        frame.add(pane);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

And just for the sake of explaining why your code isn't working is that you're fighting the layout manager, I'm getting this output in my computer when running your code:

[image]

The way to make it work is to call `frame.setLayout(null)` which again **IS NOT RECOMMENDED**, see the second paragraph of this post, if you insist on keep doing it with `null-layout` you'll just find yourself into more and more troubles as you keep adding features to your program.

After removing the layout manager:

[image]