# Append swing jbutton elements to array in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

I am working on a messaging application. The GUI is written in Java Swing. When the client starts, it asks my server for the chats a specific user is involved in. The server will send these in the form of an string array eg: `{CHAT_PATH,CHAT_PATH}`.

Once the client receives this it feeds it to my GUI class, which is supposed to display each chat name in the list (I will filter out the rest of the path) on screen listed downward. This is where my problem lies. I start by creating a `JButton` list:

```
JButton[] chat_names = {};
```

and then I loop through the list of chats (chat_data) and add to my chat_names list a new JButton for each chat name. Like this:

```
for (int x=0; x<chat_data.length-1; x++){
    chat_names[x] = new JButton(chat_data[x]);
    chat_names[x].setBounds(100,100,100,100);
}
    
for (int x=0; x<chat_names.length; x++){
    frame.add(chat_names[x]);
}
```

When I do this I get the following syntax error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of   
bounds for length 0
at gui_main.menu_screen(gui_main.java:16)
at Main.main(Main.java:89)
```

Does anyone know if this is fixable or another way I could display a list of buttons each with a `chat_name` on them.

Comment: `JButton[] chat_names = {};` Here you created an array of `JButtons` with length 0, you can either call `chat_names = new JButton[chat_data.length];` before the `for-loops` or create a `List<JButton> chatNames = new ArrayList<>()` to have a variable length list of buttons, and as a tip use `camelCase` rather than `snake_case` for your variables and methods, as that's the convention. And one more thing don't manually specify the bounds of each `JButton`, instead use a proper [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Btw you can merge both `for-loops` and include this line inside the first loop: `frame.add(chat_names[x]);`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I see what you are saying with the array. I'll go try out what you have suggested.

Comment: The first thing didn't work out but using ArrayList did, thanks again.

Comment: Then, let me add my comment as an answer for you to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you created an array of JButtons with length 0

```
JButton[] chat_names = {};
```

You can either call

```
chat_names = new JButton[chat_data.length];
```

before the `for-loops` or create a

```
List<JButton> chatNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

to have a variable length list of buttons

As a tip use `camelCase` rather than `snake_case` for your variables and methods, as that's the [convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-indentation.html).

And one more thing don't manually specify the bounds of each `JButton`, instead use a proper [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for example [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#grid) or [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box) may work. If you insist on using `setBounds` and (more than surely) `null-layout` you may find yourself in a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42521097/2180785) when trying to run it on a different computer or a different monitor.

You can also merge these 2 loops:

```
for (int x=0; x<chat_data.length-1; x++){
    chat_names[x] = new JButton(chat_data[x]);
    chat_names[x].setBounds(100,100,100,100);
}
    
for (int x=0; x<chat_names.length; x++){
    frame.add(chat_names[x]);
}
```

Into one, reducing one iteration over all the chats and thus improving performance:

```
for (int x=0; x<chat_data.length-1; x++){
    chat_names[x] = new JButton(chat_data[x]);
    chat_names[x].setBounds(100,100,100,100); //Use a layout manager!
    frame.add(chat_names[x]);
}
```